# How to change Foreground Color of each letter in a string in C# Console?

Tags: c#, console

I want to ask if how can I change a color of a specific letter in a string with a specific color i want.

For example:

```
string letters = "Hello World";  //The string inputted.
```

I want to change "o" in the "Hello" to red. How do i do that? I know that

```
Console.Foreground = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

will change the whole string to red. What would be the best code to change a specific letter with a specific color? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be

```
var o = letters.IndexOf('o');
Console.Write(letters.Substring(0, o));
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write(letters[o]);
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine(letters.Substring(o + 1));
```

You can also generalise this into a function that works for arbitrary strings or letters you want to colorise:

```
void WriteLineWithColoredLetter(string letters, char c) {
  var o = letters.IndexOf(c);
  Console.Write(letters.Substring(0, o));
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
  Console.Write(letters[o]);
  Console.ResetColor();
  Console.WriteLine(letters.Substring(o + 1));
}
```

Another option might be to use a string like `"Hell&o World"` and parse that where `&` means to print the following letter in red.

Comment: `Console.ResetColor()` can use to reset color back.

Comment: Oh, nice. Learned something new. This won't help when you change the colors elsewhere in the program, though.

Comment: It Sets the foreground and background console colors to defaults, so you don't need to keep old value and reassign it back. Anyway 1+

Comment: I know now. But the defaults are taken at the start of the program so it might not be appropriate if you're doing color stuff elsewhere (like having your program completely green on black, for example). But indeed, that's a niche thing to worry about and trivial to change for someone who does. I edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
string letters = "Hello World";
Char[] array = letters.ToCharArray();

foreach (Char c in array)
{
    if (c == 'o')
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(c);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write(c);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Read();
```

Comment: This would color the `o` in `World` as well, which wasn't a requirement as far as I understood.

Comment: True, true.  1 AM here, starting to drift.

Comment: Well, *technically* it's not wrong as the `o` in `Hello` is also red ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I found a solution that works pretty well for the original poster.

I'll give an example using a rainbow display which can be individually adapted to unique letters and colors desired in a text:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.Write("H");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow; Console.Write("e")
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; Console.Write("l");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; Console.Write("l");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; Console.Write("o ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta; Console.Write("W");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta; Console.Write("o");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan; Console.Write("r");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; Console.Write("l");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow; Console.Write("d.\n\n");
Console.ResetColor();
```

Hope this helps anyone else coming to find ways to individually color characters in a C# line.